# What determines if something is subject to probabalistic/superimposition behavior?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability, superposition

The position of electrons, or behavior of photons, is probabilistic, allows for superposition of states, and follows Schrödinger's equation for their wave functions.

But other particles like protons and neutrons don't have wave functions, and basically act like classical particles.

So is there some kind of criterion that determines when an object behaves probabilistically according to quantum mechanics? Or for what kinds of objects Schrödinger's equation is applicable for?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that protons and neutrons do not have wave functions. As far as we know, all matter obeys the Schrödinger equation, but for objects that are more and more massive, quantum effects are less and less significant, so you can model them using classical mechanics. There is no sharp cut-off between a quantum object and a classical one- it is a matter of degree. Diffraction experiments have been performed with objects thousands of time heavier than a proton.